# Making folders when the names have "/" and " ' "

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I'm building up file paths (and `mkdir`-ing them) based on variables:

```bsh
mkdir "$root_folder/$title ($year)"
```

I came across a situation where $title was `9/11: Inside the President's War Room`. The `/` is a problem because mkdir will interpret it as a folder path. So I want to replace all `/` with `\/` so that mkdir takes it literally instead of thinking it's a path. The `'` in the name is also giving problems. So I also want to replace all `'` with `\'` but this is harder than I thought.

My end goal is to just make the folders in such way that those `/` and `'` are literally interpreted. Some things I've already tried:

```bsh
title=$(echo "$title" | sed -e "s|'|$(echo "\\")\'|g")
${title/\//\\/}
#---
title=$(echo "$title" | sed -e "s|'|$(echo "\\")\'|g" -e "s|/|\\/|g")
$title
#---
mkdir "$root_folder/'$title ($year)'"
```

Answer (score 10):

Single or double quotes will not cause any problems as long as you keep the variables properly quoted at all times.

```bsh
$ title=$(cat << END_TITLE
This "is a title" with 'two kinds of quotes'
END_TITLE
)

$ declare -p title
declare -- title="This \"is a title\" with 'two kinds of quotes'"

$ mkdir "$title"      # no need to try to force extra quotes in here

$ echo $?
0
```

---

filenames **may not** contain a <kbd>/</kbd> character, no matter how hard you try to escape it. Slash is the directory separator. You'll have to substitute a different character. Suppose you choose <kbd>-</kbd>:

```bsh
mkdir "$root_folder/${title//\//-} ($year)"
```

That uses bash's [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) instead of calling out to sed.

Comment: Another option could be to fake it with a unicode [fraction slash U+2044](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2044) or [division slash U+2215](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2215)